# Condition for Folding Limit in Bedsheet Problem To Be Reached

Tags: manifolds, recreational-mathematics

In this site([https://mathimages.swarthmore.edu/index.php/Bedsheet_Problem#:~:text=The%20bedsheet%20problem%20is%20an,was%20both%20mysterious%20and%20inexplicable.](https://mathimages.swarthmore.edu/index.php/Bedsheet_Problem#:%7E:text=The%20bedsheet%20problem%20is%20an,was%20both%20mysterious%20and%20inexplicable.)) it says

> the folding limit is reached when there is not enough volume or length of the remaining paper to fill the radius section.

What it is referring to is if you take a sheet of material, folding it, folding it along the same direction again, and keep repeating. Here is a diagram:

[image]

The rectangular section is the remaining paper, and the curved part with the biggest radius is the radius section.

I am a bit confused why the quote is true. Intuitively it makes sense. But how was it proved?

Thanks. For reference, the quote is in the section called "A More Mathematical Explanation".

P.S.: It's a pity that there is no tag labelled "bedsheets". :)

Comment: I would take it to mean that the given strategy breaks down, which is what you are saying when you say intuitively it makes sense.  I would not take it to mean that there is no other way to fold the sheet more times.

Comment: @RossMillikan but why does the given strategy break down when the folding volume is more than the big semicircle's area?

Comment: When you try to fold it in half again the folded section has to go around one end.  In the diagram it looks like it is not long enough to do that.  It is the length of the folded section compared to the perimeter of the end semicircle that is the problem.

Comment: We may say that it is a problem of "applied mathematics"...